# Multiple bootstrap carousels on one page not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 Bootstrap carousels [here](http://430designs.com/tect-sl/).

If you're in Chrome and shrink the screen down to a mobile view(under 500px), you'll see the slider under "Check out our latest real rides". If you click on the arrows it behaves really weird. It keeps sliding the first slide back to the active position. Even though the other items have the active class.

Here is my JS:

```
$('#slCarousel, #real-rides-mobile').carousel({
interval: 5000  });
```

I'm not sure what's going on exactly. You can view the source right in dev tools.

Any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `display:block;` from `#real-rides-mobile .item`

The carousel is supposed to use that property.

Comment: Can't believe it was that easy. I've been on this one too long. Thanks man!!

Comment: I am glad I helped.